# Signal level from its FFT

Tags: fft, discrete-signals

Suppose I have the FFT of an arbitrary real audio signal z samples long. Is there a way to discover the signal level (intended as the largest absolute value of its samples) from the FFT without computing the inverse FFT ?
I think I have read that a trivial method exists only if the spectrum is zero-phase, but in my example the signal is an arbitrary audio signal.

Comment: For the general case, there is no way to determine the peak value of a time domain signal from it's spectrum that's more efficient than simply doing an inverse FFT.

Answer (score 1):

If you solve this problem you can determine the peak in the spectrum from the signal. If the peak is much higher than the rest of the signal you can apply some heuristics to find the periodicity in the spectrum, but in my opinion using the FFT is much simpler. I don't think that you can find a good solution in less than O(n log(n)) in the frequency domain. Otherwise, the pich detection would be an easy problem.